# Configuring SPNs for SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, kerberos, setspn

I am working with a SharePoint 2010 set up operating in Classic mode and consisting of four servers:

1. Web server
2. Application server
3. SQL server
4. SQL reporting server

The SharePoint application pools on the web server are configured to run under domain service accounts. I would like to enable Kerberos on the system to allow it to function with some third-party web parts. What I am unsure of is how to properly set the SPNs. Specifically, my questions are as follows:

1. Should SPNs for the domain service account be set for the SharePoint farm name (which is used by clients to access SharePoint) or the name of the web server? These are not the same in my implementation.
   Note: The third-party web part application is installed on the SharePoint web server and has its own application pool. This app pool is configured to use a different domain service account than the SharePoint app pools. I created SPNs for this account as well and pointed them to the name of the SharePoint web server.
2. I understand that the DNS server needs an "A" record for the SharePoint server. Similar to my above question, is this record needed for the farm name or the web server name?
3. I understand that there could be some issues with using Kerberos when SharePoint is running on non-default ports (as described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502606.aspx)). In my setup, the SharePoint website runs on the default port 80, but if I am not mistaken, the Central Admin website runs on a port that was randomly generated by the installer. As such, is it necessary to create SPNs for the http service scheme on this port as well to allow clients to authenticate to the Central Admin page?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the SPN for the AppPool account( which domains Service accounts).

If your web app configured on port 80 then you need to create the SPN for short Name and DNS name. i.e

```
Web Application (default zone)    IIS App Pool Identity   
http://portal                       vmlab\svcPortal10App
```

In this case you should have the SPN like this(one for short name(server name) and one for FQDN).

- HTTP/portal
- HTTP/portal.vmlab.local

Now if you have the Web app on non-default port.

```
 Web Application (default zone)    IIS App Pool Identity   
    http://teams:5555              vmlab\ svcTeams10App
```

Now SPN should be like this:

- HTTP/Teams
- HTTP/Teams.vmlab.local
- HTTP/Teams:5555
- HTTP/Teams.vmlab.local:5555

For compete understanding please read [this white paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23176).

In that case you have to create SPN for both...WE had same structure....our web server name is `mwf01` and web app url is `http://sp.wscheema.com`, also on non default port and we created SPN for all.

- HTTP/MWF01
- HTTP/MWF01:3133
- HTTP/mwf01.WSCHEEMA.COM
- HTTP/mwf01.WSCHEEMA.COM:3133
- HTTP/http://sp.wscheema.com
- HTTP/http://sp.wscheema.com:3133

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had reviewed that white paper, but did not see mention in it of the specific scenario where the web server and farm hostnames differ. Could you clarify how to handle the SPN setting for this specific scenario, in line with my three questions?

Comment: Could you please explain what u mean by farm name and Web server name?

Comment: The "farm" is not a physical server. It is merely a hostname used by clients to access SharePoint. In implementations with multiple web servers, it is my understanding that this allows for load balancing across the web servers. This is a moot point in my implementation, since there is only one web server, but there are still two different host names for the farm and web server.

Comment: let me ask this way....you can access the sharepoint using http://www.somename.com but you web server name is spweb01, is this correct? what port you use for the web application....if possible share the AAM settings(may be fake the url)

Comment: That's correct. The web application using the default port 80. Could you clarify what you mean by AAM settings?

Comment: alternate access mapping. check my updated anwser.

Comment: Okay, so I need to create SPNs for the domain service account running the SharePoint app pools for both the farm and web server names. That being said, as per my original post, I've already created SPNs for the domain service account running the third-party app pool for the web server name. Will this be considered a duplicate / result in a conflict?

Comment: setspn command never let you create the duplicate SPN...it will throw the errors.

Comment: I understand using setspn -s prevents duplicates. I am just asking if I should expect any issues. If I understand you correctly, I need to create SPNs as follows. SPNs for Third-Party App:
1. http/[web server hostname]
2. http/[web server FQDN]

SPNs for SharePoint:
1. http/[web server hostname]
2. http/[web server FQDN]
3. http/[farm hostname]
4. http/[farm FQDN]

Comment: i think i am missing about the 3rdparty app? what is this?

Comment: I installed a third-party application on the SharePoint web server to add some web parts. This application has its own app pool. See my original post for more details.

Comment: does that application required SPN( check with them). i dont think...i am not sure about the product....

Comment: Yes, the third-party application does require SPNs, because the app pool is running under a domain account.

Comment: if it is running under the same id and url is different then you need SPN for that url but if url is same then no

Comment: What do you mean by the URL being different? The third-party app integrates into SharePoint -- it adds additional web parts for use on SharePoint pages.

Comment: @skyfx, as i dont have information about the your 3rd party application, i cant tell it...but what i am saying if it is seprate application with seprate IIS site then you need SPN for it....webparts are usually deployed as solutions.....you can also check that vendor if they tell you how to create SPN for their app